# How to change text color depending on the number value (Using javascript)

Tags: functions, custom-field, javascript, post-meta, meta-value

I'm trying to change text on the table depending on the meta value I give (number).

- if meta value >= 7, number text on table changes to green.
- else if meta value >= 4, number text on table changes to yellow.
- else, number text on table changes to red.

However, this code doesn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function change_color_text (num1) {
        var rate_num = num1;
        if(rate_num >= 7) {
            rate_num.style.color = "green"; // green
        } else if (rate_num >= 4) {
            rate_num.style.color = " yellow"; // yellow
        } else {
            rate_num.style.color = "red"; // red
        }
    return rate_num;
    }
</script>

<?php $ccf_CAR = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ccf_CAR', true ); ?> // meta data is number value like 7,2,5 etc. (This code is working)
<?php $ccf_PSC = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ccf_PSC', true ); ?> // meta data is number value like 7,2,5 etc. (This code is working)

<figure class="wp-block-table">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Rate Subject</th>
                <th class="has-text-align-center" data-align="center">Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Safe Score</td>
                <td class="has-text-align-center" data-align="center"><p id="safe_score"><?php echo "<script> change_color_text($ccf_CAR); </script>"; ?></p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Price Score</td>
                <td class="has-text-align-center" data-align="center"><p id="price_score"><?php echo "<script> change_color_text($ccf_PSC); </script>"?></div></td>
            </tr>
            ....same code above for the table
        </tbody>
    </table>
</figure>
```

I think there's an error in javascript function or maybe I didn't write properly with this code.

```
<?php echo "<script> change_color_text($ccf_CAR); </script>"; ?>
```

Comment: The proper way in WordPress to pass variables from PHP to Javascript is to use [`wp_localize_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) (which requires that you properly enqueue your script first; see [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) for more on that topic).

Comment: @PatJ Thanks for the reply.

Comment: since `rate_num` is a number, it doesn't have a `style` property - you should be receiving the error "Cannot set properties of undefined." In any scenario, would it not be easier to simply set the `style` attribute of the elements using PHP directly?